# Changing the "this" scope of a haxe object. Possible?

Tags: design-patterns, delegates, haxe

Is it possible to change the "this" scope of an object, from the outside, very much like in javascript?

I see an interesting application, where one could create a container object, having multiple components, where every time a component modifies a property on its own, it actually implicitly modifies a property on the container.

Do not get me wrong. I know that the same effect can be achieved with events, bindings, observers, and what not. Possibilities are indeed endless. I am just curious about this funky way of delegation.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You can achieve that using [Reflect.callMethod](http://haxe.org/api/Reflect), but you must know that it won't be type-safe at compile-time. Here is a little example :

```
class Test
{
    public var a:Int;

    public function new()
    {
        this.a = 0;
    }
}

class Test2
{
    public var a:Int;

    public function new()
    {
        this.a = 0;
    }

    public function increment()
    {
        this.a++;
    }

    static public function main()
    {
        var t = new Test2();
        var t2 = new Test();
        Reflect.callMethod(t2, Reflect.field(t, "increment"), []);

        trace(t2.a); //Traces 1
    }
}
```

Comment: I had no idea that was possible... took me a while to wrap my head around it, cool hack

Answer (score 0):

Another possible way would be to use macros to rebuild your code for using some another object instead of this. However, it would be relatively hard and IMO pointless. I don't really understand your idea, but basing what I understood from your description, I'd recommend you to look into inline getters and setters on components which would also modify container.